# Specify date format in mysqldump

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate data from a `mysql` database to a MS Sql Server 2014 and I'm having problems with the dump generated by mysqldump.

The issue is because of the format of the dates, in the dump they come as:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss
```

When I insert a value with this format in sql server in a datetime column it understands it as:

```
yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.sss
```

Is there a way to tell mysqldump to use a different date format?

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT YMD ?

Comment: Moving to the dark side

Comment: That was enough @Devart, thanks

Comment: @JorgeBPrado you are welcome ;) in past i encountered the same issue...

Comment: as @Strawberry says, the dark side has this issues :$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a temporary table in Mysql after converting the date to desired format and then do mysqldump.

```
create table temp_table as
select fields, DATE_FORMAT(datefield_in_question, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s") as  datefield_in_question
from source_table;
```

The date field would be converted to string in temp_table and mysqldump would dump the field in required date format specified in sql above.